# setEmptyView() using inflated view doesn't work

Tags: android

i have a TabHost with 3 tabs, each holds a list to which i want to attach an empty-view, shown when no items exists. The layout goes like this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <ListView android:id="@+id/tab_all_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
                <ListView android:id="@+id/tab_call_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                </ListView>
                <ListView android:id="@+id/tab_sms_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                </ListView>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/empty_list_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:visibility="gone"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/location_waternark"></ImageView>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/empty_action_list_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And in code, i set the empty-view like this for each ListView (shown once for brevity):

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tab_all_list);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_list_view));
```

Still, no empty-view is shown when the adapter attached to the list has no items.
Does it have anything to do with view-heirarchies or something?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `android:id/empty` id for a view of any type as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Comment: I forgot to mention - i'm not using a ListActivity, because it's actually a TabActivity which hold 3 ListViews - 1 for each tab. Is the thing with the android:id/empty still relevant in such case?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that setting the empty-view's id to:

```
android:id="@id/android:empty"
```

solved it!

Comment: According to the docs, you *should* be able to remove the call to setEmptyView() now that you've set the view's id to "@id/android:empty"

Comment: @mharper : probably not, since he's not using a ListViewActivity